# Mysql syntax error - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

The syntax looks ok to me - but MySQL workbench complains about the last line:

```
Field20 VARCHAR(120);
```

The code being executed is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents(
DocumentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(DocumentID),
Field1 VARCHAR(120),
Field2 VARCHAR(120),
Field3 VARCHAR(120),
Field4 VARCHAR(120),
Field5 VARCHAR(120),
Field6 VARCHAR(120),
Field7 VARCHAR(120),
Field8 VARCHAR(120),
Field9 VARCHAR(120),
Field10 VARCHAR(120),
Field11 VARCHAR(120),
Field12 VARCHAR(120),
Field13 VARCHAR(120),
Field14 VARCHAR(120),
Field15 VARCHAR(120),
Field16 VARCHAR(120),
Field17 VARCHAR(120),
Field18 VARCHAR(120),
Field19 VARCHAR(120),
Field20 VARCHAR(120);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the last paranthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE Documents(
DocumentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(DocumentID),
Field1 VARCHAR(120),
Field2 VARCHAR(120),
Field3 VARCHAR(120),
Field4 VARCHAR(120),
Field5 VARCHAR(120),
Field6 VARCHAR(120),
Field7 VARCHAR(120),
Field8 VARCHAR(120),
Field9 VARCHAR(120),
Field10 VARCHAR(120),
Field11 VARCHAR(120),
Field12 VARCHAR(120),
Field13 VARCHAR(120),
Field14 VARCHAR(120),
Field15 VARCHAR(120),
Field16 VARCHAR(120),
Field17 VARCHAR(120),
Field18 VARCHAR(120),
Field19 VARCHAR(120),
Field20 VARCHAR(120));
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the statement, after the last field:

```
...
Field18 VARCHAR(120),
Field19 VARCHAR(120),
Field20 VARCHAR(120)
); --- HERE
```